# how to insert a string in a linked list inserting function

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to insert a string into `struct data_node` in a function called `insert`. My `struct data_node` is

```
struct data_node {
   char name [25];
   int data;
   struct data_node *next;
   };
```

and my insert function is:

```
struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **p_first, int elem, char *word ) {

    struct data_node *new_node, *prev, *current;
    current=*p_first;
    while (current != NULL && elem > current->data) {
       prev=current;
       current=current->next;
    } /* end while */

    /* current now points to position *before* which we need to insert */
    new_node = (struct data_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct data_node));
    new_node->data=elem;
    new_node->name=*word;

    new_node->next=current;
    if ( current == *p_first ) /* insert before 1st element */
       *p_first=new_node;
    else                       /* now insert before current */
       prev->next=new_node;
    /* end if current == *p_first */
    return new_node;
};
```

when I compile , it says that the line 22 incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[25]' from type 'char' that means `new_node->name=*word;` is wrong. how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked list structure is irrelevant. This problem boils down to copying one `char[]` to another. This will work:

```
strncpy(new_node->name, word, 25);
```

with some caveats. If `word` doesn't point to a valid `char[]`, then this could cause undefined behavior. If it points to an array containing <strike>more than 25</strike> 25 or more (non-null) characters, the operation will copy the first 25 into `new_node->name`, which means that `new_node->name` will *not* be null-terminated, which could cause trouble later if other code assumes that it is. **As WhozCraig points out, it's almost always a good idea to terminate the destination string with a null -- after being sure to leave room for it by copying one less character than you could (i.e. 25-1).** And you might consider defining a constant `NAMELENGTH` so that you don't have the magic number 25 appearing here and there in your code.

Comment: The no-termination caveat isn't just if the source string is longer than 25 non null chars, its *at least* 25 chars. Meaning a string *exactly* 25 chars long, not just longer than 25, will likewise *not terminate*. This is the reason when coding a truncation acceptance to use one-less than the target buffer length as the length parameter, and *always* hard-set the last char in the buffer to 0. If the string were shorter, the hard-set is benign (and in fact the entire tail of the buffer is already zeroed out anyway in that case).

Comment: @WhozCraig: 1) You're right, I was off-by-one. 2) You're slightly less right; setting the last char to 0, although not strictly necessary, is a good convention that I should have mentioned. I'll edit...

Comment: If you fail to terminate the string manually and the string being copied is N-length, where N is the third perimeter to `strncpy()`, it will *not* terminate the string. Setting the terminator isn't optional; its *mandatory*, particularly in the OP's case where the buffer is off a fresh malloc and thus filled with indeterminate data. Were the buffer off a `calloc` it would be optional, of course, but only if `25-1` (i.e. 24) or shorter is passed as the length.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I respectfully disagree. It will not null-terminate the string, but null-termination is not mandatory, just a good convention. As for the destination buffer starting out full of indeterminate data, it will wind up in the non-null-terminated state *only if* it has been completely overwritten with data from the source array, so I don't think we have to worry.

Comment: ok then, you're right. we will disagree, because without null-termination you don't have a C string, you have a char buffer. Do with that what you will, so long as nothing calls any C string function afterward that expects a termination char to function properly (which would be *all* of them). And the non-terminated case full-buff-case is precisely why we *do* worry.

Answer (score 0):

`data_node.data` should be `void *`. This way you can store any type (though you will have to know what type it is when reading it).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the strcpy method to copy word value in `new_node -> name`.

Take a look at [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).

```
strcpy(new_node->name, word);
```